# Does android:soundeffectsenabled override the global settings on the phone?

Tags: android, button, soundeffect

I have a button and I have set `android:soundeffectsenabled="true"`.
But this does not trigger the sound effect that I call in my `onClick()` method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id)
    {
        case(R.id.button):
            button.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            break;
    }
}
```

So was wondering the use of this attribute for a button or any other view.

I noticed that Whatsapp, for example, plays the effect without invoking the `MediaPlayer`. I can tell this by how my HTC One M-8 functions where the BoomSound icon is displayed for anything that goes through the MediaPlayer.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody? :( 

I am essentially trying to play the sound effect even if the global settings on the phone (Touch Sounds..) has been disabled. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Adding some discoveries. I figured that Whatsapp does use the MediaPlayer to output sound. I found these in the log files when I run Whatsapp:
`06-01 15:21:45.382 9394-9611/? I/MediaPlayer: reset() in
06-01 15:21:45.383 9394-9611/? I/MediaPlayer: reset() out
06-01 15:21:45.383 9394-9611/? I/MediaPlayer: release() in
06-01 15:21:45.383 9394-9611/? I/MediaPlayer: release() out`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I managed to discover the answer myself. Do note that this was specific to my requirements.

As mentioned I wanted to play a sound like a notification would. This means the volume controls are different for a notification as compared to a `MediPlayer` or `AudioManager` file being played.

So the way to do this would be:

`Uri clickSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + **your.package.name** + "/" + **resource of a sound file in the res/raw folder**);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, clickSoundUri);
r.play();`

Thats it. And you can put this code inside your button's `onClick()` method and play the sound. This gives the user the option of controlling the audio and notification volumes separately.